# Warframe Sys [Error]: Cache manifest body not found on cache server

Tags: linux, warframe

I have a linux mint 17 os. I installed wine-staging. I installed steam for wine. I installed warframe through steam.

```
/opt/wine-staging/bin/wine Warframe.exe
```

When I run warframe using the above command

```
1.834 Sys [Warning]: Bad data from cache host content.warframe.com for /B.Cache.bin!0A_VNCkZTjVlLwt4wneUUdfTQ
1.836 Sys [Error]: Cache manifest body not found on cache server
```

I receive the following error message. Is this a wine problem or is this a server problem? I would like to avoid setting up a VNP connection if possible.